# Generics in a Dictionary as an Input in a method

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a method that accepts a Dictionary as an input.

However, when I try to add the following:

```
 public void WriteToJsonFile(Dictionary<string, T> dicList)
 {
 ... stuff
 }
```

It will state that T is missing an assembly or reference. Now, I have worked around this by adding a

```
<T>
```

to the class name so it will be a Generic Class. Am I using the Dictionary class properly as all I want is to create a method that will accept a Dictionary where the key is a string but the value can be of any object?

Comment: You can add <T> to method name instead of whole class to make it generic public void WriteToJsonFile<T>(Dictionary<string,T> dicList)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have worked around this by adding a `<T>` to the class name so it will be a Generic Class.

You should not do this, unless you have a specific need for the class to be generic.

> all I want is to create a method that will accept a Dictionary where the key is a string but the value can be of any object?

All you need is a `Dictionary<string,object>` then: this way, a single dictionary could have objects of different types, all keyed by string. Even better, you could use `IDictionary<string,object>` to let your class users pass other implementations of `IDictionary<K,V>` interface.

Comment: Would it be better to use a generic method or use IDictionary<string, object>? I am not sure whether WriteToFile<T>(Dictionary<string, T> diclist) might be better than WriteToFile(Dictinoary<string, object> diclist)?

Comment: @SamIAm The difference between the two approaches is that `IDictionary<string,object>` lets the caller mix objects of different kinds within the same dictionary, while `IDictionary<string,T>` requires all dictionary objects to be of the same type within a single call. In other words, `IDictionary<string,T>` would let you write a dictionary of string to int, and then a dictionary of string to double, but not a dictionary that mixes ints with doubles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making generic method you should actually mark it as generic:

```
    public void WriteToJsonFile<T>(Dictionary<string, T> dicList)
    {

    }
```

and you should add using for System.Collections.Generic;